# How to fix default table number and description separator

Tags: captions, longtable, tabularx

I have 2 tables using different packages, but the caption gennerate different:

When I use table with `tabularx`:

> Table 1 – A simple example

When I use `longtable`:

> Table 2: A simple example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{0.4in}|p{2in}|p{3.3in}|}
    % first head
        \caption{caption.\label{tab:table1}} \\
        \hline a & b \\
    \endfirsthead
    \endhead
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
        \hline a1 & b1 \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{table}[htb]
        \caption{caption.\label{tab:table2}}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
        \hline a & b \\
        \hline a1 & b1 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! We would need a minimal working example that reproduces the problem. It is not `longtable` nor `tabularx` that change caption formatting.

Comment: @Bernard -- `longtable` *does* redefine `\caption`.  that said, it's still necessary to know what document class is used, since that will define the "default" style.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new in LaTeX. My source code is big, have many archieves and folders, and I don't know what I post here. So I create a little project in https://pt.sharelatex.com/templates/5630d7dfa8610a850fa5cc4c . The numbers and sections are messed, but in the original file are OK.

Comment: @barbara beeton: Longtable redefines label separator, label font and the like??? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @YitzhakStone Please, try to reduce the code to a simple short complete document that you can add as an edit to your question; otherwise, you might find that some users (myself included) won't be willing to go to an external site to look for the code.

Comment: I'll do it, @GonzaloMedina!

Comment: @Bernard -- there's the command `\let\caption\LT@caption`, which does ultimately result in a changed style, the one with the colon (having just looked it up).  this has been encountered at ams; the caption style doesn't match what's defined in `amsart` et al., and it always needs to be changed.  (which is a pain.)

Comment: I found what is causing this: \usepackage[...]{babel}. I changed to use only english. But if anybody can explain more details as answer...

Comment: Despite the answer below works fine, I preffer remove a language and work with only one in babel package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround. Use

```
\usepackage[labelsep=colon]{caption}
```

after `\usepackage[english,french]{babel}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[labelsep=colon]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{0.4in}|p{2in}|p{3.3in}|}
    % first head
        \caption{caption.\label{tab:table1}} \\
        \hline a & b \\
    \endfirsthead
    \endhead
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
        \hline a1 & b1 \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{table}[htb]
        \caption{caption.\label{tab:table2}}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
        \hline a & b \\
        \hline a1 & b1 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]